# JQuery Letters fade in randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first time coding in JQuery. Below is my code:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('fadeletters1'),
  letters = div.textContent.split('');

while(div.hasChildNodes()) div.removeChild(div.firstChild);

for(var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
  var letter = document.createElement('span'),
    style = 'opacity ' + (Math.random() * 5 + 1) + 's linear';
  letter.appendChild(document.createTextNode(letters[i]));
  letter.style.WebKitTransition   = letter.style.transition = style;
  letter.style.opacity = 0;
  div.appendChild(letter);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < div.childNodes.length; i++) {
    div.childNodes[i].style.opacity = 1;
  }
}, 0);
```

```html
<div id=fadeletters1>Helllooo This is a test for the website</div>
```

So the letters do fade in but then in the starting of the animation, letter are kinda visible and then fades in after couple seconds. I want it to pop up from 0 visibility to 100 visibility as its fades in.

I am trying to acheive something like this site does: http://method.digital/

Comment: I tried experimenting with these numbers but its not that what I am trying to achieve. basically when the site loads I want letters in random positions to fade in. currently I am seeing all the letters slightly visible when the site loads and then random letters fade in or brightens up.

Comment: I think I understood after seeing the example on the linked site (I didn't realise it appeared before scrolling down after a delay!), see if what I've posted is what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're changing the rate at which the transition takes place, instead you want to change the delay before the transition starting:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('fadeletters1'),
  letters = div.textContent.split('');

while(div.hasChildNodes()) div.removeChild(div.firstChild);

for(var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
  var letter = document.createElement('span'),
    style = 'opacity 0.6s linear',
    delay = (Math.random() * 4) + 's';
  letter.appendChild(document.createTextNode(letters[i]));
  letter.style.WebKitTransition   = letter.style.transition = style;
  letter.style.WebKitTransitionDelay   = letter.style.transitionDelay = delay;
  letter.style.opacity = 0;
  div.appendChild(letter);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < div.childNodes.length; i++) {
    div.childNodes[i].style.opacity = 1;
  }
}, 0);
```

```html
<div id=fadeletters1>Helllooo This is a test for the website</div>
```

---

If you want to run it for multiple divs you can wait until the first is complete before moving onto the next (this example only appears to work sometimes, make sure to hit refresh before running):

```js
function RunAnimation(target,delay) {
  var div = document.getElementById(target),
      letters = div.textContent.split('');

  while (div.hasChildNodes()) div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
      var letter = document.createElement('span'),
          style = 'opacity 0.6s linear',
          delay = (Math.random() * 4) + 's';
      letter.appendChild(document.createTextNode(letters[i]));
      letter.style.WebKitTransition = letter.style.transition = style;
      letter.style.WebKitTransitionDelay = letter.style.transitionDelay = delay;
      letter.style.opacity = 0;
      div.appendChild(letter);
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < div.childNodes.length; i++) {
        div.childNodes[i].style.opacity = 1;
      }
    }, 0);
  }, delay);
}

RunAnimation('fadeletters1')
RunAnimation('fadeletters2', 5000);
RunAnimation('fadeletters3', 10000);
```

```html
<div id="fadeletters1">Helllooo This is a test for the website</div>
<div id="fadeletters2">This is a second div which also fades in</div>
<div id="fadeletters3">And who knows maybe you want a third</div>
```

Comment: Yes! This works. One more thing:  How can hide this text and move to the next word?

Comment: @GauravKumar Well you know (from the numbers that I've used), that it will take at most 4.6s to finish (max 4s for the delay and 0.6s for the actual change), you could set a timeout of say 5000ms at which point you remove the div and add another one, then run the code again for the new div

Comment: @GauravKumar I've added a way that you could do it, take a look

Comment: I wanna hide the first letter and position it on top of that and keep it looped. What adjustment will I have to do for this? BTW thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is there is two delays...

One for the animation and one for a timeout. This is the timeout that really gives the effect you are looking for.

```js
// Get the letters from the original string.
var letters = $("#fadeletters1").text().split("");
// Remove the original string.
$("#fadeletters1").text("");

// Create a span for each letters and append them to the document.
letters.forEach(function(item,index){
  var span = $("<span class='fade'>").text(item);
  $("#fadeletters1").append(span);
});

// Animate each spans
$(document).find(".fade").each(function(){
  // Random delay
  var delay = Math.random();
  var letter = $(this);
  
  // Set a timeout to animate the spans
  setTimeout(function(){
    letter.animate({"opacity":1},delay*1000);
  },delay*3000);
});
```

```css
.fade{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="fadeletters1">Helllooo This is a test for the website</div>
```